# Can I consider this project as a framework?

Tags: c#, frameworks

I have a trivial question about a framework. I have written a project including some classes.
Among the classes, I have an abstract class with two methods. Another class is inherited from this class which owns more specialized methods.

Can I refer to this program as a framework or not?

Answer (score 1):

A framework is something you can build an application upon. If your classes may be used in general, name your code a library. A framework throws in a specific style and philosophy, and you usually can't build anything you like without conforming to minimum rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But will it be accepted by others as such?

A set of classes is usually called a toolkit. A framework is like a massive structure on which you can build customized applications.